# popup open same window with autoclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a one popup ads network code which open on my site popup window advertisement.
this popup code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = '16';
var wid = '4';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adscpm.net/member/popads.js"></script>
```

like i use this popup code on my site this page
http://www.vube.pk/ads.html

its working fine when open this page and when click any where on this page popup open.

but i want something change i want when open this page
http://www.vube.pk/ads.html

auto popup open with click and also this popup open on this same page not open different
please tell me any JavaScript code force to run this popup same window without click

Answer (score 0):

in `parent`.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var output = "data";
        var OpenWindow = window.open("child.html", "mywin", '');
        OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output; // dataFromParent is a variable in child.html
        OpenWindow.init();
    });
</script>
```

in `child.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFromParent;    
    function init() {
    //trigger click event of button here.this will show popup
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i don't know what you say what is parent.html and child.html tell me i add popup script how to open same my page without any click on this page http://www.vube.pk/ads.html

Comment: In your case, parent and child html are same. just make sure you add init function in your html.  and use first block of code for opening the new tab. Also add trigger of click function in init.